# Can not update my pod library

Tags: ios, iphone, git, cocoapods

I have published my component HDTableDataSource on Cocoapods. I have now updated the version of the code by adding some code.

While trying to compile it using command "pod spec lint", it gives me following error.

```
[!] /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/\<GITHUB_USERNAME\>/HDTableDataSource.git /private/var/folders/fm/vxq9zgy52zq28lvcq0qwzpj80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/HDTableDataSource --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.1.0

Cloning into '/private/var/folders/fm/vxq9zgy52zq28lvcq0qwzpj80000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/HDTableDataSource'...

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/HDTableDataSource.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

Kindly help me to update my library.
My Library is at https://github.com/HarshitDaftary/HDTableDataSource

Comment: Have you properly created git tag and updated podspec?

Comment: Yes I created git tag and also pushed them.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes finally I got the solution. I am shortly deleting this question.

Comment: Please find my answer @ChamiraFernando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this problem solved by executing following command

```
pod spec lint HDTableDataSource.podspec
```

My mistake was I was executing 'pod spec lint' , I didn't pass the podspec file with it.

Thanks all for your response. I will delete this question soon.